# Compare two array and find match in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

```
for(var i = 0; i < textList.length; i++){
    for(var j = 0; j < titles.length; j++){
        if(textList[i] === titles[j]){
            console.log ("it includes my " + titles[j] + ' the match is ' +textList[i] + " counter " + i)
        }
    }
}
```

this is my code, but it won't return a match. I tried == and ===. But when i tested .includes() it worked. Can someone explain what's happening ?

Comment: you're aware that Java isn't JavaScript, right?

Comment: print both variables in an else block, and see what the difference is. without knowing the input, we can't know what is going wrong

Comment: if you can show us the two arrays then that would be great.

Comment: Agree with the above, this could be an issue with your inputs but without examples it is difficult to say

Comment: Why some people post the question and then run ? :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all elements are in type String, you can use the method .search():

[Prototype search](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search)

It will return the position of the match, if it dosent match in any position you will get -1 as return, soo > 0 it match.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code with a very basic test example as follows:

```
let textList = ['book1', 'book2','book3']

let titles = ['book', ' tester', 'not_this', 'book2']

for(var i=0; i<textList.length;i++){
    for(var j=0; j<titles.length;j++){
        if (textList[i] === titles[j]){
            console.log ("it includes my " + titles[j] + ' the match is ' +textList[i] + " counter " + i)
        }
    }
}
```

And I got the expected result `it includes my book2 the match is book2 counter 1` so with this specific code I would suggest looking at you input arrays.

With regards to your question regarding why `.includes()` works and this doesn't, again we would need to se your input arrays but I would hazard a guess that it is something to do with the type checking within this function.

Finally, as others have suggested, there are other (more succinct) ways of achieving this with built in array functions, however your original question was about why this code in particular doesn't work so I've left these out.